# Uploading an image/various info via SOAP in Drupal

Tags: drupal, soap, wsdl, cck, nusoap

I've tried quite a few options and I just simply have no clue what I'm doing.  I do program in PHP, but this SOAP/wsdl stuff is all new to me.

I need to allow a desktop app to upload an image + other info to my Drupal powered site, preferably uploading to the table of CCK content type I have set up.  I also need to provide the dev of the desktop app with a wsdl file.

I believe I want to use nusoap, maybe through the soapclient drupal module?  The problem is there is 0 documentation in the soapclient module, so I'm kind of confused as to where to even start.

Obviously, this is a pretty big undertaking and I'm just hoping to be pointed in the right direction, with any hints or tips as to how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I did this using XML RPC.

I ended up solving this problem using the following blogs/modules...

- DrutNet allowed me to have an example of a C# application that uploaded a CCK file.  http://www.gizra.com/content/code-sample-drutnet
- This article on Salmon Run taught me how to make a custom service, which helped me solve some issues  http://sujitpal.blogspot.com/2010/10/custom-drupal-xmlrpc-service.html, this groups.drupal post also helped: http://groups.drupal.org/node/107289
- Finally, using this blog post, I learned about inserting nodes programmatically... http://www.unleashed-technologies.com/blog/2010/07/16/drupal-6-inserting-updating-nodes-programmatically

I hope this helps someone down the line.  If anyone has any questions, answer this thread with them and I'll respond when Stack emails me.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the direction you are trying to send images, I think your best choice is Services module: http://drupal.org/project/services

I think you'll find some entries about image uploads in the issue queue.

Comment: hmm, I'm working with services now.  I can't find any examples that involve image upload, unfortunately. :-/  Thanks though!